Why does Gstreamer have such bad performance when used with GTK4?
I'm trying to build a very simple Rust GUI application to run on Raspbian OS Lite under a Raspberry Pi 4b. Problem is that once the application is started, the video runs at a constant 1 frame per second and is unwatchable.
Here is a base implementation that reproduces the effect, note that I also tried this under Ubuntu Server 22.04 and got the same exact results as with Raspbian OS Lite:
use gstgtk4::PaintableSink;
use gstreamer::prelude::*;
use gstreamer::ElementFactory;
use gtk4::gdk::Paintable;
use gtk4::prelude::*;
use gtk4::{Application, ApplicationWindow, Box, Orientation};
 
fn main() {
    let app = Application::builder()
        .application_id("com.example.Gtk4Gstreamer")
        .build();
 
    app.connect_activate(build_ui);
    app.run();
}
 
fn build_ui(app: &Application) {
    let window = ApplicationWindow::builder()
        .application(app)
        .title("GTK4 GStreamer Example")
        .default_width(800)
        .default_height(600)
        .build();
 
    // Create a vertical box to hold the video
    let vbox = Box::new(Orientation::Vertical, 0);
    window.set_child(Some(&vbox));
 
    gstreamer::init().unwrap();
    gstgtk4::plugin_register_static().expect("Failed to register gstgtk4 plugin");
 
    let sink = ElementFactory::make("gtk4paintablesink").build().unwrap();
 
    let playbin = ElementFactory::make("playbin")
        .property(
            "uri",
            format!(
                "file://{}",
                "/home/user/test-rust/src/1yIfdmUlqmzvY8dLU6xG6WBvlkwmKkFmS"
            ),
        )
        .property("video-sink", &sink)
        .build()
        .unwrap();
 
    let pipeline = gstreamer::Pipeline::new();
    pipeline.add(&playbin).unwrap();
 
    let gtk4paintablesink = sink
        .dynamic_cast::<PaintableSink>()
        .expect("Sink element is expected to be a Gtk4PaintableSink!");
 
    let paintable = gtk4paintablesink.property::<Paintable>("paintable");
 
    let image = gtk4::Picture::for_paintable(&paintable);
    vbox.append(&image);
 
    // Start playing the pipeline
    match pipeline.set_state(gstreamer::State::Playing) {
        Ok(state) => state,
        Err(e) => {
            panic!("Failed to set the pipeline to the `Playing` state: {}", e)
        }
    };
 
    // Show the window
    window.show();
}

I also tried the following command directly using Gstreamer which renders the video way better:
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/... ! decodebin ! autovideosink
Is there anything I'm missing? Could it be caused by a problem within gtk4paintablesink itself?
EDIT
I added a way to force a specific framerate. I haven't tried it on the Pi yet, but it seems functional through WSL2. I'll give feedback once I have.
fn build_ui(app: &Application) {
    let window = ApplicationWindow::builder()
        .application(app)
        .title("GTK4 GStreamer Example")
        .default_width(800)
        .default_height(600)
        .build();

    // Create a vertical box to hold the video
    let vbox = Box::new(Orientation::Vertical, 0);
    window.set_child(Some(&vbox));

    gstreamer::init().unwrap();
    gstgtk4::plugin_register_static().expect("Failed to register gstgtk4 plugin");

    let sink = ElementFactory::make("gtk4paintablesink").build().unwrap();
    let videorate = ElementFactory::make("videorate").build().unwrap();
    let capsfilter = ElementFactory::make("capsfilter")
        .property(
            "caps",
            &gstreamer::Caps::builder("video/x-raw")
                .field("framerate", &gstreamer::Fraction::new(60, 1))
                .build(),
        )
        .build()
        .unwrap();

    // Create a bin to hold the videorate and capsfilter elements
    let bin = gstreamer::Bin::new();
    bin.add_many(&[&videorate, &capsfilter, &sink]).unwrap();
    gstreamer::Element::link_many(&[&videorate, &capsfilter, &sink]).unwrap();

    let bin_pad = videorate.static_pad("sink").unwrap();
    let ghost_pad = gstreamer::GhostPad::with_target(&bin_pad).unwrap();
    bin.add_pad(&ghost_pad).unwrap();

    let playbin = ElementFactory::make("playbin")
        .property(
            "uri",
            format!("file://{}", "/home/user/test-rust/src/4702-720.mp4"),
        )
        .property("video-sink", &bin)
        .build()
        .unwrap();

    let pipeline = gstreamer::Pipeline::new();
    pipeline.add(&playbin).unwrap();

    let gtk4paintablesink = sink
        .dynamic_cast::<PaintableSink>()
        .expect("Sink element is expected to be a Gtk4PaintableSink!");

    let paintable = gtk4paintablesink.property::<Paintable>("paintable");

    let image = gtk4::Picture::for_paintable(&paintable);
    vbox.append(&image);

    // Start playing the pipeline
    match pipeline.set_state(gstreamer::State::Playing) {
        Ok(state) => state,
        Err(e) => {
            panic!("Failed to set the pipeline to the `Playing` state: {}", e)
        }
    };

    // Show the window
    window.show();
}

EDIT
I tried the code above on the Pi 4, it does not work, I still get the same exact problem. I have also tried changing from a gtk4::Picture to a gtk4::Image, without success. I will investigate further.

"1 fps" makes me wonder if the video playback is limited by the window refresh rate

Since it's pretty much constant, that could make sense, but I really don't see why it'd be capped. When running the gstreamer command I get great performance and there doesn't seem to be much in the docs as far as refresh rate goes for paintable/gtk4paintablesink

I'm going to try adding something similar to "videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=60/1" in my rust code just to make sure

Try using "audiovideosink" instead of "gtk4paintablesink", I think the latter is tied to the gtk loop. The former should let GStreamer go straight through

I believe you mean "autovideosink". I tried it a while back but the problem was that it needed a window handle based on the specific display manager used. It was sketchy and seemed limited in its features when used with Gtk4.

I added the code in my post to force the framerate to 60, I'll try it when i can on the Pi

Yep my b. Good luck

What about using gtk4 from the cli? E.g. gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///path/to.mp4 video-sink=gtk4paintablesink

I get the following: WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not set property "video-sink" in element "playbin0" to "gtk4paintablesink"

Could you try setting the "sync" property of the  gtk4paintablesink element to false?
